# UIBarButtonItem Appearance and first Application Start

Tags: ios, ipad, uibarbuttonitem, appearance

we use the appearance system of iOS 5 to style our application, we also style the UIBarButtonItem like this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button 
   forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    normalColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
    [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
    [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:kFontSize], UITextAttributeFont,
    nil] 
  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But have a buttonitem at the start view controller of our navigation view controller, but the first time this screen is displayed this button has its default background.

When I change the order of both statements the button has the correct background but the wrong text.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, typo. Where do you have this code?

Comment: I placed this code in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method